# I can't install the created module it gives a series of mistakes

Tags: python, odoo-10

I am creating an Odoo module, it has a doctor, specialty and appointment, tree and form views. I have done it following a template given by the teacher but it gives me a series of errors when installing.
These are the errors:

````
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 368, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 82, in load_module
    exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/etc/odoo/custom-ADDONS/hospital/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/etc/odoo/custom-ADDONS/hospital/models/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    consultas = fields.selections(
AttributeError: module 'odoo.fields' has no attribute 'selections'
```
````

These are the classes of the different models:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

# class hospital1(models.Model):
#     _name = 'hospital.hospital'

#     name = fields.Char()
#     value = fields.Integer()
#     value2 = fields.Float(compute="_value_pc", store=True)
#     description = fields.Text()
#
#     @api.depends('value')
#     def _value_pc(self):
#         self.value2 = float(self.value) / 100
class medicos(models.Model):
    # nombre del modelo
    __name = 'hospital.medicos'

    name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True,
                       size=40, help="Introduzca el nombre")
    domicilio = fields.Char(string="domicilio", required=True,
         size=40, help="Introduzca el domicilio")
    telefono = fields.Integer(
        string="telefono", required=True, size=9, help="Introduzca el telefono")
    fecha = fields.Date(string="Fecha ingreso", required=True)
    especialidad_medico = fields.Many2one(
        'hospital.especialidad', string="Especialidad")
    citas_medico = fields.One2many(
        "hospital.citas", "medico_cita", string="Citas del medico")


class especialidad (models.Model):
    # nombre del modelo
    __name = 'hospital.especilidad'


name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True,
                   size=40, help="Introduzca la especialidad")
consultas = fields.selections
    ([('1', 'consulta 1'), ('2', 'consulta 2'), ('3', 'consulta 3'), ('4', 'consulta 4'),
    ('5', 'consulta 5')])
medico_esp = fields.One2many(
    'hospital.medicos', 'especialidad_medico', string="Especialidad")
citas_esp = fields.One2many(
        "hospital.citas", "especialidad_citas", string="Citas del medico")


class citas (models.Model):
    # nombre del modelo
    __name = 'hospital.citas'
    paciente = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True,
                           size=40, help="Introduzca del paciente")
    fecha_cita = fields.Datetime(string="Fecha de la cita", required=True)
    especialidad_cita = fields.Many2one(
        'hospital.especialidad', string="Especialidad")
    medico_cita = fields.Many2one(
        'hospital.medicos', string="Medico")
```

This is what I have, modified according to what you have told me and the errors that the odoo program gives me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting KeyError for field "medico_citas", This is from your "citas_medico" field definition:

```
 citas_medico = fields.One2many(
        "hospital.cita", "medico_citas", string="Citas del medico")
```

the mandatory syntax for One2Many field is

```
field_name = fields.One2many(comodel_name, inverse_name, string)
```

here

```
     comodel_name = name of the target model
     inverse_name = name of the inverse Many2one field in comodel_name
```

Please check [Odoo  ORM API doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields)

here error is because there is no "medico_citas" field in your "hospital.cita" object.

Please check your code fully after going through the ORM API doc.
and one more thing there is no need of two underscore for name defintion in class

```
_name = 'a.model.name'
```

Correction eg:

Change this:-

```
 citas_medico = fields.One2many(
        "hospital.cita", "medico_citas", string="Citas del medico")
```

to ->

```
 citas_medico = fields.One2many(
        "hospital.citas", "medico_cita", string="Citas del medico")
```

And this:-

```
medico_cita = fields.Many2one(
    'hospital.medico', string="Medico")
```

to ->

```
medico_cita = fields.Many2one(
    'hospital.medicos', string="Medico")
```

Please check every relational field like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok and then how would it be?
doctor_date = fields.One2many (
         "hospital.cita", "medico_cita", string = "Doctor appointments")
If there is a medical field, quote the last line of the class.

Comment: Look what you have put change one thing to another and the 2 things put the same. Nothing changes

Comment: model name "hospital.cita" chages to "hospital.citas" and inverse_name  "medico_citas" changes to "medico_cita". Please note the spelling

Comment: not keep giving error modify the question so that you see how I have it

Answer (score 0):

It's the common mistake for odoo developers.

Please don't use **selections**

Use this in your class (**hospital.especilidad**):-

```
consultas = fields.Selection([('1', 'consulta 1'), ('2', 'consulta 2'), ('3', 'consulta 3'), ('4', 'consulta 4'),('5', 'consulta 5')])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field named `selections` as indicated in `hospital/models/models.py` line 40.

I can see in your code that you used `_name` in the commented code which is correct but you used `__name` in the rest of your code, You will see the following warnings in the log:

```
Field medicos.especialidad_medico with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.especialidad'
Field medicos.citas_medico with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.citas'
Field especialidad.medico_esp with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.medicos'
Field especialidad.citas_esp with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.citas'
Field citas.especialidad_cita with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.especialidad'
Field citas.medico_cita with unknown comodel_name 'hospital.medicos'
```

And Odoo will raise a `KeyError`, for example:

```
`KeyError: 'medico_cita`
```

`medico_cita` should be the inverse field name of the `citas_esp` One2many field defined in `medicos`

***To fix those errors changes `selections` to `Selection` and `__name` to `_name`.***